# Beamer: Onslides messes up tcbraster

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, tcolorbox, overlays, alignment

I have issues with my beamer presentation: I want to have 3 boxes next to each other, they should first appear all at the same time and then I would specify when the boxes should appear. Without \onslide everything works well, but when I include \overlay, things get messed up:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}




\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster column skip=0.05cm, size=small, raster force size=false,size=fbox]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, valign=center, colframe=blue!80!black, colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=3.9cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4.1cm]
        bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster column skip=0.05cm, size=small, raster force size=false,size=fbox]
    \onslide<1->{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, valign=center, colframe=blue!80!black, colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=3.9cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
    \onslide<1,2->{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
    \onslide<1,3->{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4.1cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first two slides which this code produces are the following:
[image]

As you can see, the alignment in the second slide isn't like I wanted, I don't want a linebreak here. What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two solutions: If I change the width of the boxes (I was not respecting \textwidth before) and make them smaller, everything works well. But my text is a bit too long for that and the possibly nicer way to do it is inspired by a comment from @samcarter: Just insert a % after the { of \onslide. Both solutions:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}  %% Themenwahl

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster column skip=0.05cm, size=small, raster force size=false,size=fbox]
    \onslide<1->{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, valign=center, colframe=blue!80!black, colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=3.5cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
    \onslide<1,2->{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=3.5cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
    \onslide<1,3->{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4.1cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster column skip=0.05cm, size=small, raster force size=false,size=fbox]
    \onslide<1->{%
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, valign=center, colframe=blue!80!black, colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=3.9cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
    \onslide<1,2->{%
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
    \onslide<1,3->{%
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4.1cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`tcolorbox v4.20` introduced some `beamer support` options. With them you can apply specific options every slide or hide boxes in particular slides.

Following code adapts OP's second frame to `tcbitemize` and shows how to use `hide` and `alert` options to show every new box one after the other:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\tcbset{beamer alerted/.style={}}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster column skip=0.05cm, size=small, raster force size=false,size=fbox]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, valign=center, colframe=blue!80!black, colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=3.9cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4cm]
            bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, colframe=blue!80!black,colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, width=4.1cm]
        bla 
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3, raster column skip=0.05cm, size=small, 
    raster force size=false, 
    size=fbox, enhanced,
    halign=center, valign=center, colframe=blue!80!black, colback=blue!10!lightgray!30, ]
   \tcbitem[width=3.9cm]
            bla 1
   \tcbitem[width=4cm, hide=<-1>, alert=<2>]
            bla 2
   \tcbitem[width=4.1cm, hide=<-2>, alert=<3>]
            bla 3
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: In previous code I had to use a forced combination of `hide` and `alert` options to show the third box. I think `hide` should be enough. I will update the answer if I find a better solution.